# C# Xamarin.IOS / MonoTouch - App Opening Firing Event

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, xamarin.ios

In my C# Xamarin.IOS/Monotouch project, I load all basic content of my view into my MainViewController within the ViewDidLoad() method.

If I then press the home button on my iPhone and navigate to another app on my phone, and then subsequently click the icon of my app again (which is still running in the background), and open it.....

**....what event get's fired at that point?**

I can see that ViewDidLoad does not get fired at this point.
I can also see that ViewWillAppear does not get fired at this point either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's documentation around backgrounding can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html. You should be able to override the `WillEnterForeground` method to run your code when the application awakes from the background.

From my understanding, `ViewDidLoad` is the method that gets called the first time a view opens and that's the only time it gets called. `ViewWillAppear` gets called when the view gets navigated to from a different view.